# Unity3D / Vuforia AR Camera not showing camera feed on camera background

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am evaluating Unity3d 2017.4.2f2 with Vuforia and Xcode 9.3 for an AR App and have the problem, that the camera background works in the simulator but not on the iPad pro with iOS 11.3,1.

It seems to be a known problem and I checked nearly every solution including using XCode9.2 and copying the device config, deleting Metal from the Vuforia Settings, creating new AR Cameras, even the latest Unity3D beta and whatnot. The background does not show up and I get the following error:

```
2018-05-03 14:53:33.396112+0200 ProductName[2340:1694266] ERROR/AR(2340) 2018-05-04 14:53:33: CameraDevice::getCameraCalibration(): Failed to get camera calibration because the camera is not initialized.
```

and

```
cameraDeviceStartCamera
2018-05-03 14:53:33.460389+0200 ProductName[2340:1694266] ERROR/AR(2340) 2018-05-04 14:53:33: VideoBackgroundConfig with screen size of zero received, skipping config step
```

If there is anything else I can do or that points me into the right direction is appreciated. many thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah that's an issue with the IOS 11.3. If you could downgrade it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Unity3D completely and reinstalling the latest Unity3D version and the VuforiaSupportInstaller-Mac-7-1-35 solved it. Both accessible via the [Vuforia Download page](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure check if you did all of this:

- In player settings enable Vuforia's support
- Go to player settings >> Other Settings and check Camera Usage Description field

Then you can try one of the following suggestions:

- change the Target resolution to native (default device resolution)
- set the graphics to be OpenGLES2.0 instead of automatic

If this doesn't work you can also try to delete the meta data of the camera controller script.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I think I did all of this. But I just started an empty project to double check.